# Meaning of ちゃっかり in ちゃっかり口には入れてた

Tags: meaning, adverbs

I found a definition for ちゃっかり:自分の利益のために抜け目なく振る舞うさま however I'm still not quite sure of the nuance of this word example below.

> 「ムキィッ！　カズさんだけズルイよ！みんな、僕にも『あーん』してっ？」
>
> ジュー！
>
> ジュー！
>
> ジュー！
>
> 「ぎゃあああぁぁああっっ！！？って、みんな僕になんか恨みでもあるの！？」
>
> 「あ、ごめん……つい……」
>
> 「ふ、ふぇ……」
>
> 「わ、悪い……」
>
> 「まったくもう……もぐもぐ……カズさんにばっか、もぐぐ……贔屓するんだから……もぐもぐ」
>
> 「**ちゃっかり口には入れてた**んだな……」

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at more than one dictionary.

For instance, the 精選版 日本国語大辞典 entry [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A-566823#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8) lists the following definition, which seems to fit your context better:

> 〘副〙 抜け目ないさま、ずうずうしいさまを表わす語。